# C2337 'importidl': attribute not found error after upgrading solution to VS2019 ( 16.9.2 )

Tags: windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors, com

I am updating a project to compile with VS2019 and turns out that [importidl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/attributes/importidl?view=msvc-160) is no longer supported in VS2019 ( 16.9.2
). Comparing the generated .tlb prior to updating to VS2019 and after the binary file is much smaller resulting in a broken COM interface.

The error I am getting is `C2337 'importidl':attribute not found`.

The `importidl` is surrounded by a warning suppression:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4467)
[ importidl(COM\\dummy.idl) ];
#pragma warning(pop)
```

`C4467: usage of ATL attribute is deprecated`

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/attributes/importidl?view=msvc-160) leads to believe that `imporidl` had not been deprecated or removed. However, it has been last updated 2 years ago and the warnings and errors are leading me to believe that there is a discrepancy on the documentation.

What is the alternative to go around the removed `importidl`?

Comment: import? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/attributes/import?view=msvc-160

Comment: You want to to convert and IDL to TLB?  Or a TBL to an IDL?  What programming language to you ultimately want to use?

Comment: I want to convert from IDL to TBL. This is so other people can write scripts/automation using this COM interface. I believe the language does not matter.

Comment: It’s great that you posted a self-answered question. But the question needs a lot more detail. You said “importidl is no longer supported in VS2019” when it’s clearly documented as supported. Please show sample code and explain exactly what is it that you experienced including any error message. Without that information nobody can understand the question or provide alternative answers (which might for example explain why the issue happens) and others are unlikely to find the question/answer if they encounter the same problem. Include the exact release of VS2019 as it is updated often.

Comment: @EuroMicelli thank you for the feedback. I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this issue with VS2019, I added a `/permissive` flag to the command line option. Setting the conformance mode to "No" along with the `std:c++latest` did not work. `std:c++latest` is probably overriding `/permissive`.

[image]

Keeping the conformance mode to `Default`, with the latest `/std:c++latest` language standard and adding `/permissive` as an additional Options to the command line property goes around the error `C2017 Importidl attribute not found`.
[image]